# Can JAX-RS @Path specify length requirements?

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

I've been using `@Path("{id: [a-zA-Z0-9-]*}")` to capture an intended identifier with the URL.

Works fine, but I'd like to ensure those identifiers are between 1-64 characters long.

According to the Java Reg Exp docs something like `@Path("{id: [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,64}}")` ought to work but instead I'm met with `HTTP 405`.

What's the magic here I'm missing? I'm really wanting to apply simple request validation.

Update: Removing the end hyphen causes things to come to life. Note sure why yet...

Comment: I have tried your example using jersey 1.12 and it works as expected. The path is not matched if "id" is not within limits(1,64) and i get 404 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found the solution:

```
@Path("{id: [a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,64}}")
```

The end hyphen needed escaping.

Comment: One of the many reasons why I like Intellij IDEA (community version) is that it detects these types of regex errors.

Comment: @Augusto Yep but use of Java EE means Intellij rather expensive for us :(